# Apply clipPath to transformed g element

Tags: svg

I'm trying to clip a circle so that it only shows for the part that falls within certain bounds. However, the circle is within a g element that is transformed. When I apply the clip path to either the g element or the path within this element ("g.site" or "g.site path") the circle complete gets clipped off. Short example showing my problem:

```
<svg width="600" height="600">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <path d="M435.1256860398758,144.76407538624122L419.76193083948306,273.83328117717105L469.9933509829825,301.0396981292212L483.3234271019269,296.67464757752555L535.23683445551,247.72472220603692L574.3496211247055,127.3184557867296Z"
      />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="voronoi">
    <g id="cells">
      <path class="cell" d="M435.1256860398758,144.76407538624122L419.76193083948306,273.83328117717105L469.9933509829825,301.0396981292212L483.3234271019269,296.67464757752555L535.23683445551,247.72472220603692L574.3496211247055,127.3184557867296Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g id="sites">
      <g class="site" transform="translate(483.29548177370367,267.14072835257724)" clip-path="url(#myClip)">
        <path fill="rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)" d="M0,30A30,20 0 1,1 0,-30A30,20 0 1,1 0,30M0,1A1,1 0 1,0 0,-1A1,1 0 1,0 0,1Z"
        />
      </g>
      <g class="site" transform="translate(483.29548177370367,267.14072835257724)">
        <path fill="rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)" d="M0,30A30,20 0 1,1 0,-30A30,20 0 1,1 0,30M0,1A1,1 0 1,0 0,-1A1,1 0 1,0 0,1Z"
        />
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

A working demo of my problem can be found in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xRh6A/

I added two circles. The first one is clipped off (because the clip-path attribute is set), the second is shown but (obviously) not clipped.

I suppose this is related to the fact that the clip-path is defined in absolute terms while the circle element has local coordinates and is then transformed. Can I use the clipPath with a transformed group or do I have to either change the clip path or the circle path in order to make them match?

**Edit** I solved it by placing the "sites" with absolute coordinates. However, this meant that I couldn't use d3.svg.arc (which is generating the code in the simplified example I attached) because it creates arcs in a local coordinate system.

I'd still be interested to see if it could be solved otherwise as well.

Answer (score 20):

Your translation on the `g` element is affecting how the `clipPath` is rendered. You have 2 options:

1. Add the `clip-path` attribute to a static parent element. You can then apply your translation on the child element without it affecting the `clipPath` rendering.
2. Apply the inverse translation on the `clipPath` element. I've never implemented this method, but I read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16166249/3123187. This option requires that you update the `clipPath` tranform each time you change the `g` transform.

In your case, you already have a parent `g` element so you can add the `clip-path` attribute there, if you intend to apply the `clipPath` to every element in your `g#sites` element.

```
<g id="sites" clip-path="url(#myClip)">
  <g class="site" transform="translate(483.29548177370367,267.14072835257724)">
    <path fill="rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)" d="M0,30A30,20 0 1,1 0,-30A30,20 0 1,1 0,30M0,1A1,1 0 1,0 0,-1A1,1 0 1,0 0,1Z" />
  </g>
  <g class="site" transform="translate(483.29548177370367,267.14072835257724)">
    <path fill="rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)" d="M0,30A30,20 0 1,1 0,-30A30,20 0 1,1 0,30M0,1A1,1 0 1,0 0,-1A1,1 0 1,0 0,1Z" />
  </g>
</g>
```

(jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SWyeD/)

If you only intend for that `clipPath` to be applied to the first circle, you'd just add an intermediate container element.

```
<g id="sites">
  <g clip-path="url(#myClip)">
    <g class="site" transform="translate(483.29548177370367,267.14072835257724)">
      <path fill="rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)" d="M0,30A30,20 0 1,1 0,-30A30,20 0 1,1 0,30M0,1A1,1 0 1,0 0,-1A1,1 0 1,0 0,1Z" />
    </g>
  </g>
  <g class="site" transform="translate(483.29548177370367,267.14072835257724)">
    <path fill="rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)" d="M0,30A30,20 0 1,1 0,-30A30,20 0 1,1 0,30M0,1A1,1 0 1,0 0,-1A1,1 0 1,0 0,1Z" />
  </g>
</g>
```

(jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bdB65/)