# Clip path only working once on page load in d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am currently trying to implement a clipPath to my candlestick chart in d3. It works as intended, once and only once, if I change the width and height of the rect in the clipPath I can see candlesticks dissappear but when I draw them past the bounds of the clipPath they still remain.

```js
var width = 600;
var height = 500;

var marginTop = 20;
var marginBottom = 20;
var marginLeft = 60; //initial space required to the left of the chart
var marginRight = 20;

var candleWidth = 20;
var candleGap = 40;
var candleMargin = 10;
var padding = 70;
var Xpadding = 60;

var wickThickness = "2";

var hLineColor = "#b5b6b7";


var data = [{
  Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
  High: 118.81,
  Low: 116.86,
  Open: 118.75,
  Close: 117.34
}, {
  Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
  High: 118.11,
  Low: 116.08,
  Open: 117.05,
  Close: 116.28
}, {
  Date: 03 / 12 / 15,
  High: 116.79,
  Low: 114.22,
  Open: 116.55,
  Close: 115.2
}, {
  Date: 04 / 12 / 15,
  High: 119.25,
  Low: 115.11,
  Open: 115.29,
  Close: 119.03
}, {
  Date: 07 / 12 / 15,
  High: 119.86,
  Low: 117.81,
  Open: 118.98,
  Close: 118.28
}, {
  Date: 05 / 01 / 16,
  High: 105.85,
  Low: 102.41,
  Open: 105.75,
  Close: 102.71
}, {
  Date: 04 / 02 / 16,
  High: 97.33,
  Low: 95.19,
  Open: 95.86,
  Close: 96.6
}, {
  Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
  High: 118.81,
  Low: 116.86,
  Open: 118.75,
  Close: 117.34
}, {
  Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
  High: 118.11,
  Low: 116.08,
  Open: 117.05,
  Close: 116.28
}, {
  Date: 03 / 12 / 15,
  High: 116.79,
  Low: 114.22,
  Open: 116.55,
  Close: 115.2
}, {
  Date: 04 / 12 / 15,
  High: 119.25,
  Low: 115.11,
  Open: 115.29,
  Close: 119.03
}, {
  Date: 07 / 12 / 15,
  High: 119.86,
  Low: 117.81,
  Open: 118.98,
  Close: 118.28
}, {
  Date: 05 / 01 / 16,
  High: 105.85,
  Low: 102.41,
  Open: 105.75,
  Close: 102.71
}, {
  Date: 04 / 02 / 16,
  High: 97.33,
  Low: 95.19,
  Open: 95.86,
  Close: 96.6
}];

var maxi = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.value;
}); // to check what the max value in the data array is ... for info purposes
console.log(maxi); //not displaying in brackets??

// .map() creates an new array based on function
var maxLow = d3.min(data.map(function(x) {
    return x["Low"];
  })) // returns the lowest value of 'low'
var maxHigh = d3.max(data.map(function(x) {
    return x["High"];
  })) // returns the highest value of 'high'
var maxMinDiff = (maxHigh - maxLow) * 0.1;
console.log(maxMinDiff);

//function that will return the lowest of two numbers a or b
function min(a, b) {
  return a < b ? a : b;
};

//function that will return the highest of two number a or b
function max(a, b) {
  return a > b ? a : b;
};

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickSize(-height);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width);

var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([-width / 2, width / 2]).range([0, width]);

//Var Y is a function that will scale the numbers on the Y axis from an input domain into output range; height-0 which inverts or flips Y otherwise visualisation is upside down
var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([maxLow - maxMinDiff, maxHigh + maxMinDiff]) //changed to reflect new variables for lowest, highest and difference to define input domain
  .range([height - marginTop - marginBottom, 0 + marginLeft + marginRight]); //range has still not been modified ... remember x,y have been reversed to reflect y,x


//this section is very similar to mashup code at #2
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(x)
  .y(y)
  .scaleExtent([1, 32])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);
var chart = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg:svg") //namespace prefix
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var grid = chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "gridding");


//script to create horizontal lines for viewing
var lines = grid.selectAll("line.y")
  .data(y.ticks(20))
  .enter()
  .append("svg:line")
  .attr("class", "y")
  .attr("x1", marginLeft)
  .attr("x2", width - marginRight)
  .attr("y1", y)
  .attr("y2", y)
  .attr("stroke", hLineColor);

var numbers = grid.selectAll("text.yrule")
  .data(y.ticks(10))
  .enter()
  .append("svg:text")
  .attr("class", "yrule")
  .attr("x", marginLeft / 2)
  .attr("y", y)
  .attr("dy", 0)
  .attr("dx", 20)
  .style("fill", "#b5b6b7")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")

chart.append("chart:clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("clip-path", function(d, i) {
    return "url(#clip)";
  })
  .attr("width", width - padding)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("x", Xpadding - 15)




var candlestick = chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "candlesticks")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")



//function to build a chart using data in var data
//.call zoom and append g enable pan and zoom ... still not perfect ... don't want y axis moving etc
function buildChart(data) {






    //script for creating the candlestick wick that will lie behind the rectangle//x1 y1 represent High and x2 y2 represent Low
    //coded first to sit beneath the rectangle
    var wicks = candlestick.selectAll("wick")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("x1", function(d, i) {
        return candleMargin + marginLeft + candleWidth / 2 + (candleGap * i);
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
        return candleMargin + marginLeft + candleWidth / 2 + (candleGap * i);
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return y(max(d.High, d.Low));
      }) //return which ever is highest value H or L using var y for scaling
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return y(min(d.High, d.Low));
      }) //return which ever is lowest value H or L using var y for scaling
      .attr("stroke", function(d) {
        return d.Open > d.Close ? "#a01f1b" : "#1ba048";
      })
      .attr("stroke-width", wickThickness);



    //script for creating rectangle representing Open and Close positions
    //                            chart.selectAll("rect")
    var candle = candlestick.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return candleMargin + marginLeft + (candleGap * i);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(max(d.Open, d.Close));
      }) //top left hand corner of rectangle coordinates
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(min(d.Open, d.Close)) - y(max(d.Open, d.Close));
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return candleWidth
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return d.Open > d.Close ? "#a01f1b" : "#1ba048";
      })
      .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).on("zoom", function() {
        candlestick.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")")
      }));

  } //closing brackets for buildChart function
buildChart(data);


function zoomed() {
  svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
  //svg.select(".rect").call(chart);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the code for the ClipPath and adding to my group of rectangles

```
  chart.append("clipPath")
                     .attr("id","clip")
                     .append("rect")
                     .attr("width", width-padding)
                     .attr("height", height)
                     .attr("x", Xpadding-15)




                var candlestick = chart.append("g")
                .attr("class", "candlesticks")
                .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
```

If you run the code Snippet you should see that if you pan any of the rectangles to either the left or right (The boundary to the clipPath is the axis lines) the rectangles wont be masked out, Now if you alter the width or height value of the clip mask you can clearly see rectangles being masked i.e half a rectangle being removed but again when I pan zoom nothing happens

Comment: There's far too much code here. Please create a [mcve] and explain clearly what it's supposed to look like and what it actually does look like.

Comment: Hope that makes it clearer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is essentially a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164565/clip-path-and-translate-in-g-tag-svg/16166249#16166249).  I was going to close it but since that one is not `d3` and see a bunch of other bad practices in your code I decided to type up an answer.

**First**, your clip-path doesn't work because you are applying a `translate` to the object being clipped and the clip-path is then following that `translate` as well.  The simple solution is to wrapper it in another `g`.

```
var candlestick = chart.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "candlesticks");
```

**Second**, your dates are not dates but a division equation.  You aren't using them so I didn't mess with it.

**Third**, you seem to be suffering from the *too many margins, I don't know where to apply them problem*.  Begin your chart construction in a sane way (by creating a `g` with your margins) and then only deal with width/height.  I like to start with Bostock's [classic bar chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) example's first 30 lines or so and build off of that for new visualizations.

**Fourth**, you probably want to apply the zoom/pan on the entire chart, not just mouse-events on the candles.

Putting this all together:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>

    var candleWidth = 20;
    var candleGap = 40;
    var candleMargin = 10;

    var wickThickness = "2";

    var hLineColor = "#b5b6b7";
    
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 60},
      width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    var data = [{
      Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
      High: 118.81,
      Low: 116.86,
      Open: 118.75,
      Close: 117.34
    }, {
      Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
      High: 118.11,
      Low: 116.08,
      Open: 117.05,
      Close: 116.28
    }, {
      Date: 03 / 12 / 15,
      High: 116.79,
      Low: 114.22,
      Open: 116.55,
      Close: 115.2
    }, {
      Date: 04 / 12 / 15,
      High: 119.25,
      Low: 115.11,
      Open: 115.29,
      Close: 119.03
    }, {
      Date: 07 / 12 / 15,
      High: 119.86,
      Low: 117.81,
      Open: 118.98,
      Close: 118.28
    }, {
      Date: 05 / 01 / 16,
      High: 105.85,
      Low: 102.41,
      Open: 105.75,
      Close: 102.71
    }, {
      Date: 04 / 02 / 16,
      High: 97.33,
      Low: 95.19,
      Open: 95.86,
      Close: 96.6
    }, {
      Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
      High: 118.81,
      Low: 116.86,
      Open: 118.75,
      Close: 117.34
    }, {
      Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
      High: 118.11,
      Low: 116.08,
      Open: 117.05,
      Close: 116.28
    }, {
      Date: 03 / 12 / 15,
      High: 116.79,
      Low: 114.22,
      Open: 116.55,
      Close: 115.2
    }, {
      Date: 04 / 12 / 15,
      High: 119.25,
      Low: 115.11,
      Open: 115.29,
      Close: 119.03
    }, {
      Date: 07 / 12 / 15,
      High: 119.86,
      Low: 117.81,
      Open: 118.98,
      Close: 118.28
    }, {
      Date: 05 / 01 / 16,
      High: 105.85,
      Low: 102.41,
      Open: 105.75,
      Close: 102.71
    }, {
      Date: 04 / 02 / 16,
      High: 97.33,
      Low: 95.19,
      Open: 95.86,
      Close: 96.6
    }];

    var maxi = d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.value;
    }); // to check what the max value in the data array is ... for info purposes
    //console.log(maxi); //not displaying in brackets??

    // .map() creates an new array based on function
    var maxLow = d3.min(data.map(function(x) {
        return x["Low"];
      })) // returns the lowest value of 'low'
    var maxHigh = d3.max(data.map(function(x) {
        return x["High"];
      })) // returns the highest value of 'high'
    var maxMinDiff = (maxHigh - maxLow) * 0.1;
    //console.log(maxMinDiff);

    //function that will return the lowest of two numbers a or b
    function min(a, b) {
      return a < b ? a : b;
    };

    //function that will return the highest of two number a or b
    function max(a, b) {
      return a > b ? a : b;
    };

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .tickSize(-height);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
      .tickSize(-width);

    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([-width / 2, width / 2]).range([0, width]);

    //Var Y is a function that will scale the numbers on the Y axis from an input domain into output range; height-0 which inverts or flips Y otherwise visualisation is upside down
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([maxLow - maxMinDiff, maxHigh + maxMinDiff]) //changed to reflect new variables for lowest, highest and difference to define input domain
      .range([height, 0]); //range has still not been modified ... remember x,y have been reversed to reflect y,x


    //this section is very similar to mashup code at #2
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .x(x)
      .y(y)
      .scaleExtent([1, 32])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);
      
    var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
      
    var grid = chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "gridding");

    //script to create horizontal lines for viewing
    var lines = grid.selectAll("line.y")
      .data(y.ticks(20))
      .enter()
      .append("svg:line")
      .attr("class", "y")
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("x2", width)
      .attr("y1", y)
      .attr("y2", y)
      .attr("stroke", hLineColor);

    var numbers = grid.selectAll("text.yrule")
      .data(y.ticks(10))
      .enter()
      .append("svg:text")
      .attr("class", "yrule")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", y)
      .attr("dy", 0)
      .attr("dx", 20)
      .style("fill", "#b5b6b7")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")

    chart.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);
      
    chart.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "pane")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .call(zoom)
      .style("fill","none")
      .style("pointer-events", "all");

    var candlestick = chart.append("g")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "candlesticks")

    //function to build a chart using data in var data
    //.call zoom and append g enable pan and zoom ... still not perfect ... don't want y axis moving etc
    function buildChart(data) {
      
      //script for creating the candlestick wick that will lie behind the rectangle//x1 y1 represent High and x2 y2 represent Low
      //coded first to sit beneath the rectangle
      var wicks = candlestick.selectAll("wick")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("x1", function(d, i) {
          return candleMargin + candleWidth / 2 + (candleGap * i);
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
          return candleMargin + candleWidth / 2 + (candleGap * i);
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          return y(max(d.High, d.Low));
        }) //return which ever is highest value H or L using var y for scaling
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          return y(min(d.High, d.Low));
        }) //return which ever is lowest value H or L using var y for scaling
        .attr("stroke", function(d) {
          return d.Open > d.Close ? "#a01f1b" : "#1ba048";
        })
        .attr("stroke-width", wickThickness);

      //script for creating rectangle representing Open and Close positions
      //                            chart.selectAll("rect")
      var candle = candlestick.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
          return candleMargin + (candleGap * i);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(max(d.Open, d.Close));
        }) //top left hand corner of rectangle coordinates
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return y(min(d.Open, d.Close)) - y(max(d.Open, d.Close));
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return candleWidth
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return d.Open > d.Close ? "#a01f1b" : "#1ba048";
        })
        .style("pointer-events", "none");

    } //closing brackets for buildChart function
    buildChart(data);


    function zoomed() {
      candlestick.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")")
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I figured out the translation part last night but hadn't gotten around to making an answer but thank you, those other problems you outlined are appreciated too, the pan zoom one specifically was something bothering me so thank you again for clearing that up!